# Craft CMS 3 Boilerpoint Web Project Setups Available?

Tags: templating, setup

Does anyone have any recommended boilerpoints or guides on setting up Craft CMS 3 with front-end tooling? Looking for an initial install to be setup properly with a preconfigured database, NPM, node.js, Sass, and page templates configured to get any web project started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point would be the nystudio107 or marbles craft scaffolding projects:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft

https://github.com/Marbles/craft

Comment: Thanks Steven! I know I'm late to replying, but yeah I stumbled on nystudio a while back and has been a great resource.